# Python permission denied linux

Tags: python, linux

The command that I am using:

```
python3 -m venv /pyenvs/calculo-bonus
```

The error that I am getting:

```
Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/pyenvs/calculo-bonus/pyvenv.cfg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
python3 -m venv calculo-bonus
```

You don't have to specify the full path

There are more details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: @gabriela no problem. I am glad that I could help. If my answer helped you please mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First try to activate the environment
`source /pyenvs/calculo-bonus/bin/activate`

And then use `python3` in that environment.

A [detailed doc](https://python-guide-kr.readthedocs.io/ko/latest/dev/virtualenvs.html) for more clarification.